# Redirect image load requests in a WebBroswer control to a different location?

Tags: vb.net, image, browser

I am trying to make a html editor that allows you to preview the code as you type.

The users are able to see a live preview of the text they're typing. What I'm trying to do is get the webbrowser to load images from a different location. So, when the user changes the text in the richtextbox, the webbrowser.documenttext is changed to the text of the richtextbox and the page is loaded. But, if the code contains images, the webbrowser won't load them because there isn't any file, just the documenttext. The richtextbox is linked with the actual file itself, but I can't make it constantly write text to the actual file because that would make the save function pointless. Writing the text to another file in the same location isn't an option either, because that is too slow.

So, how can I make the webbrowser read the images from a self-selected directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the file:// path for the image.  For example:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var html = @"<body><p>Hello world</p><img src=file://c:/temp/test.png></body>";
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah but that code only works for img tags, and pages go a lot deeper (background images for example), and to make a system that detects each tag is way to much work. Can't you just override a function of the WebBrowser somehow?

Comment: No, the browser has no context when you assign the DocumentText property.  The Url is about:blank.  Full paths are required.